# Is there a term for the "maximum layer size" of an XML document?

Tags: xml

XML document depth is the length of the maximum path from the root element to a leaf.
Is there a word to describe the "breadth" of the document, by which I mean the maximum number of children of a single node?

So, in the document:

```
<A>
 <B>
  <C></C>
  <C></C>
 </B>
 <B>
  <C></C>
  <C></C>
  <C></C>
  <C></C>
  <C></C>
 </B>
</A>
```

that number would be 5 (because there are five children to the second B element and that's the largest number in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard the term "fan-out"; one can talk of the average fan-out or the maximum fan-out. But I wouldn't use the term without explaining what you mean by it.

Answer (score 0):

`Breadth` could work. I would also consider 'Branching Factor' to follow tree nomenclature.

Comment: I clarified the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's called  `Depth`.

I don't know if it is an official term, but that is what most people call it.

Comment: I clarified the question, I thought "depth" is used for the distance from root to leaf in the tree (in this case, A-B-C is the greatest distance, so the depth is 3); that is not what I am asking for